# JSON validation using Scala

Tags: json, scala, validation, playframework

I am trying to write a scala application for JSON validation. I have a Animals.scala class that defines the following:

```
case class Animals (id: Int, type: String, targets: String)

object Animals {

    implicit val reads: Reads[Animals] = (
           (JsPath \ "id").read[Int] and
           (JsPath \ "type").read[String] and
           (JsPath \ "targets").read[String])(Animals.apply _)

}
```

I have Application.scala where I have tried to validate an incoming JSON against the case class.

```
object Application extends Controller {

  // action for JSON validation
  def validateRequest = Action { implicit request =>
    // this will fail if the request body is not a valid json value
    val bodyAsJson = request.body.asJson.get

    bodyAsJson.validate[Animals] match {
      case success: JsSuccess[Animals] => {
        val id = success.get.id
        Ok("Validation passed! id is "+ id)
      }
      case JsError(error) => BadRequest("Validation failed!")
    }
  }

}
```

And finally here's my JSON input:

```
{
"id" : 1,
"type" : "domestic",
"targets": {
     "AND": [
         {
         "breed": ["greyhound", "dalmatian"]
         },
         {
         "NOT": {
             "color": ["amber", "pale_amber", "black"]
             }
         },
        {
        "zipcode": ["90210", "90211"]
        }
    ]
 }
}
```

And I get the following error:
    `JsError(List((/targets,List(ValidationError(error.expected.jsarray,WrappedArray())))))`

I do realize that the error is thrown because `targets` field is not as simple as a `String` compared to my JSON. How do I wrap it so that the validation passes? Should I do `List[List[String]]` or something along those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the structure of targets read it as a JsObject.  It will parse any internal structure that way.

Comment: Thanks! That passed the validation. How hard would it be if I were to validate the contents of `targets` too or what would be the right approach to do so?

Comment: implement classes and `Reads` for them so that they adhere to the structure of your json